# mysql UUID as String How to speed up my queries

Tags: php, mysql, uuid

I have my UUIDs as strings, I have thousands of items in my database.  My queries that seem even basic seem to takes seconds and seconds to load - when I do more complex ones we're talking minutes of time.

I believe my biggest bottleneck is that I am doing string comparisons thousands of times

Is there a way to leave my database as is - but convert the query syntax to cast the UUIDs as numbers?

Or if that is not going to help how do I go about converting my strings to numbers?

Thank you

Edit:

I have 16 tables all interconnected so difficult to post how all of them are interconnected but here is a few samples:

```
field  Type
UUID - TEXT 

"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UUID = '$custUUID'";
```

if I run it from phpmyadmin this simple query takes .7 seconds and I try to do this hundreds of times = looong loading time

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.6967 sec )
SELECT * 
FROM customer
WHERE UUID = '1234'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is an example of a more complex query that takes a LONG time 
reportdate, contract_UUID, customer_UUID, garcom_UUID and city_UUID are all of type text

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.weekreportDate FROM contract_sales a 
    INNER JOIN contract b ON a.contract_UUID = b.UUID
    INNER JOIN geoPoint c ON b.customer_UUID = c.customerUUID
    WHERE c.garcom_UUID = '$garbcom'
    AND c.city_UUID = '$cit' ORDER BY `report_date`";
```

Here is an image of one of the tables in the phpmyadmin
http://prntscr.com/1airfd

Comment: Could you post your table structure and/or the queries you're running? It might be as easy as optimizing your indexing, but it's hard to say without seeing more information.

Comment: Can you post the queries that you're running, and the table structures, if possible?

Comment: As long as the column is indexed, it should work about as well if it's a string or number.

Comment: added more info! Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: UUID should be stored as a 16 byte value (in fact it is a 16 byte value) to get a better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

Shorten your `UUID` fields to 16 char from 128

Make sure all your UUID fields are indexed.

Don't `SELECT *`,  It's bad practice and it can increase your load times. Just select what you need.

You say you use

```
"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UUID = '$custUUID'";
```

thousands of times. Would it be possible to do this:

```
"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UUID IN ( '".implode(',',$custUUID)."')";
```

where $custUUID is an array of UUIDs?

Comment: thanks for info - when you say UUID fields are indexed... I have an ID column as the primary index, can I have something else indexed as well?

they implode I am not familiar with but from what I understand I would pass in all the custUUIDs instead of one at a time, and it would give me all the results at once... In this instance I am creating a table where there is a new row for each custUUID - so dont think this will work?

Comment: Yes - you can have more than one index on a table and that might be all you need. `implode` and using `SELECT ... WHERE ... IN (...)` might allow you to pass all the CUST UUIDs in one query and get all the results back at once. It might not work for you, but if you're making thousands of requests optimising your queries should be high on your list of priorities.

Comment: I believe I did this correct - Can't find much info on this using my keywords I am trying in google... But I shorten them to 36 characters (in order not to truncate) and added two indexes on my contract table - one for the contracts UUID and one for the customers UUID a (1:1 relationship)- then did the same for the customers table http://prntscr.com/1al7ab

Comment: And the result? Did things improve?

Comment: I have about 30 places I need to probably do that - but didn't want to change them all if it sounded like I was doing it wrong... I do feel like there MIGHT be a small improvement in time (my query takes 2 minutes instead of 3 minutes) but I think it might just be a placebo effect - I havent timed it out yet.... But that screen shot is correct? and that is what I should continue to do?

Comment: @morty346 Looks fine. If this is where your bottleneck is then you should see an improvement, but anywhere you still have unindexed UUIDs you'll still have a performance problem. Also, if you're sending lots of small queries there'll be a performance problem anyway - one big one will be MUCH faster. Do your timings and see how it goes.

Comment: I appreciate the help - one more quick question I have been putting the size of the indexes to 36 (same size I put for the UUID) - but from a few links im starting to think that is wrong... and its the amount of space allowed for this index to take up...

Comment: The length parameter is used to limit the index key to the first _n_ characters of the column. For your UUID scheme this could truncate the UUID that's indexed (but not the data in the column). If your UUID is less than 36 characters you could use this to index just the significant part of the field. It will reduce index size and thus improve performance. However, I doubt you'll see a significant improvement unless you have **very** large table. For safety, stick with what you have.

Comment: def huge improvements - much more work ahead of me to get these switched over from varchar I believe - but a big help and gets my by for now so I can focus on more important things - appreciate all the help! @MikeW

Comment: Good news - glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a faster way that I bumped in while looking at my use case.

Sweet & short - Convert all your string fields(UUID's) to integers(that can be indexed by calculating the unique key using **SHA hash function**(we will talk of collisions, but that's another time)
Here's the simple way to do this (Paramters depend on your individual unique(sub fields, or part of thereof)

```
select distinct(CONV(SUBSTRING(CAST(SHA(Concat(text_field_1,text_field_2)) AS CHAR), 1, 16), 16, 10))
from table_name

#Post this you will get integer mappings(which can be readily indexed) like -:
"14686325187172356814"
"4176431494776658251"
"17905162221625924418"
"17418684985242853706"
"2795298138913147719"
"17371106411384154394" .. more
```

the other-way of course (the grind, that is) would have been to create a drop down list of these unique combinations - which is then indexed in these buckets - which is what SHA really does - assigning buckets)

As you noticed I am actually CREATING a unique (primary) key by merging two columns text_field_1 &text_field_2 . You can take substrings or whatever best fits your datatype and range. The explanation for the numbers here, 16, 1, 16,10 and how to design this SHA function is elaborated here -
http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2010/03/generating-unique-integer-ids-from-strings-in-mysql/